When to call .Save on an element in an OpenXML document?
Different parts of the OpenXML-SDK's DOM has a Save method. Do we need to save the parts while modifying the document, or do we only need to save it once when I are done creating/modifying the document?
Is it enough to call methods corresponding to these:
DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.PresentationPart.Presentation.Save()
DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Save()

And thereby avoid calling methods like these:
DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Worksheet.Save()
DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation.Slide.Save()

The reason I ask, is because the samples I've seen call Save on both the sheets and slides in addition to the workbook and presentation.

As it stands right now - at least in my current testing, I'm not calling Save anywhere and I'm not having any issues with output to the xlsx file I am creating.
I'm writing creating a MemoryStream and then writing to a FileStream - no reported issues when writing 600,000 rows.
for example:
MemoryStream memoryStream = new();
using (SpreadsheetDocument _document = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(memoryStream, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
{
    WorkbookPart wbp = _document.WorkbookPart ?? _document.AddWorkbookPart();
    wbp = SetDataOnSheet(wbp, excelContent);
   // _document.Save();// <= This is not needed and has no effect on my file.
}
return memoryStream;

and in the "SetDataOnSheet" function, I add Workbook, Worksheetparts, Worksheets, etc... I take my list of data, I format it to cells and then append each row to it before adding the data to the worksheet.
MemoryStream is then written out: (you may need to do memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);)
using (FileStream fs = new("yourfile.xlsx"), FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
{
    memoryStream.CopyTo(fs);
    fs.Flush();
}

At no stage do I call save.   An example I could possibly think of where you need to save on the fly might be where data is being provided in real time and if you don't save it, it's gone... then there would be a real need to save on the fly to a file.  Probably situational, I guess.
